# Can I Use MathJax In Gitbook.com

Tags: mathjax, gitbook

I have one gitbook ebook in gitbook.com:[here](https://wxyyxc1992.gitbooks.io/datascience-practice-handbook/content/nlp/languagemodel.html).But the mathjax plugin perform well in editor while the math expression can't seen in online version? is there any setting i need to set?

Comment: Have you seen https://plugins.gitbook.com/plugin/mathjax?

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.gitbook.com/editing-content/rich-content/with-command-palette#equations-and-formulae

Answer (score 2):

> ## Math & TeX
>
> GitBook supports math equations and TeX thanks to plugins. There are currently 2 official plugins to display math:
>   mathjax and katex.
>
> ### Enable a math plugin:
>
> To enable math support, you need to add one of these plugins to your
>   book.json:
>
> ```
> {
>     "plugins": ["mathjax"]
> }
> ```
>
> ### Differences between MathJax and KaTeX
>
> The mathjax and katex plugins are different implementations of TeX
>   equation rendering, backed by their respective Open Source libraries:
>   KaTeX and MathJax. MathJax supports the entire TeX syntax, but the
>   output is not perfect on ebooks (PDF, ePub and Mobi). KaTeX renders
>   perfectly on all formats (web and ebooks), but doesn't yet support all
>   the syntax.
>
> ### Add math to your content:
>
> ```
> Here is some inline math: $$a \ne 0$$
> ```
>
> A block of math should begin with a new line:
>
> ```
> Here is a block of math:
>
> $$
> a \ne 0
> $$
> ```

From: http://help.gitbook.com/format/math.html

Comment: The OP seems to be asking for books hosted on GitBook.com. How can he modify the `book.json` file in that context?